# Sending an array/set via to PHP via $.ajax. PHP adding a number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to send an array to the PHP script:

```
usedAnswers = [1,2];

    // funtion for displaying a question
    displayQuestion = () => {

        $.ajax({
            url: "backend/retriveData.php",
            data: {usedAnswers:usedAnswers} ,
            type:"post",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

    // inital display of question
    displayQuestion();
```

Then when I want to access the array in the PHP script

```
<?php
echo print_r($_POST['usedAnswers']);
?>
```

I get the following problem on screen

[image]

Why is he adding an extra 1 ?

When I try to access the first element of the Array like this:

`echo print_r($_POST['usedAnswers'][0]);`

He console.logs me the number 11?

What am I doing wrong what is the correct way to send an Array via Ajax?

Is it also possible to send a set via Ajax?

Comment: Because you're doing `echo print_r....` remove the `echo`, it's not necessary.

Comment: there are so many things here that dont make sense to do, its hard to unravel what youre after.  Why are you print_r'ing the payload from $_POST back to the client?  are you trying to send a multi-dimensional array? are you sending it in a json string?

Comment: @DevDonkey I want to send just a normal Array to the backend PHP and Im not quite sure whats the easiest way?

Comment: You've hit on the easiest way, you just have a syntax error that is marring your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, based on your comments, it appears your question is really referring to how to send data through, rather than the odd output you're getting, which Jay has already answered for you.

as far as your code reads, what you're actually sending is this:

```
{[1, 2]:[1, 2]}
```

which is invalid JSON.

if you're trying to actually have a 'usedAnswers' key (which it looks like from your php), then you need to do this:

```js
        $.ajax({
            url: "backend/retriveData.php",
            data: {'usedAnswers':usedAnswers}, // <-- note the quotes around the key
            type:"post",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: But when I send it like Jay said,  I just get the Array without the number 1. Could you elaborate what {'usedAnswers':usedAnswers} does?

Comment: it creates a json string with the key of `"usedAnswers"`, with an array of values, supplied by your variable `usedAnswers`.  So `{"usedAnswers": [1, 2]}`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are echoing the `print_r()` (which in and of itself is a type of `echo`) you're returning a value for the truthiness of the `print_r()`. Change the line to this

```
print_r($_POST['usedAnswers']);
```